# How can I serve requests to one Apache controlled directory to standalone CherryPy?

Tags: lamp, cherrypy

I have an existing web application in a sub folder such as domain.com/myapp/.

I wish to replace this with a CherryPy app running it's standalone server, whilst not affecting other web apps running via Apache on the same domain.

How can I do this on a LAMP stack?

Can I symlink the folder to the CherryPy root or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `domain.com` is served by a single Apache instance you can configure a Proxy/ReverseProxy pair to your standalone CherryPy application. It should be something like:

```
ProxyPass         /myapp  http://localhost:8080/myapp
ProxyPassReverse  /myapp  http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

Assuming your `myapp` server runs on localhost on port 8080.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had previously glanced at [CherryPy's docs on ModProxy](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModProxy) for Apache and CherryPy to play together, but was hoping there would be some way to avoid the CherryPy bound requests passing through Apache completely. Their location section example at the end of the page contains the code sample like yours and gives me a clear picture of how to implement it.